# How to compare two array & print original array having whole data different color unmatched data

Tags: php, arrays

How to compare two array & print original array having whole data with different color unmatched data

Like: 
Array 1 = my name is thomas
Array 2 = my name thomas

Result should be : my name **is** thomas

Comment: you can write your customer method to check if the value exist or not and store index of that if not exist in second array. at the time of printing the array value change the color if index matched with index stored

Comment: thanks, i solved it